# SQL join two columns if one is blank

Tags: sql

I have one mapping table with different geographical resolutions. The user enters data into a table and I'm trying to join the data table to the mapping table with the condition that if you can join on zipcode value then join if zip isnt available then join on city.

Is is possible to do this within a join?

Comment: Why can't you join all the data by the city?

Comment: Better use where clause in this case.

Comment: Are you saying you have a column in the mapping table that contains both ZIPs and cities?

Comment: Sorry guys been offline for a few days fallen I need to use the moset detail geography possible so has to be zip but 20% of the time zip isn't provide but city is.

Answer (score 0):

I would you something like this in your where clause:

WHERE a.ZipCode = ISNULL(b.ZipCode, a.ZipCode)
AND a.City = ISNULL(b.City,a.City)

Answer (score 0):

Depending what your data looks like, you can use an OR in your JOIN clause

```
SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN b
ON a.Zip = b.Zip
  OR a.City = b.City
```

or union two queries together

```
SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN b
ON a.Zip = b.Zip

UNION

SELECT *
FROM a
JOIN b
ON a.City = b.City
  AND a.Zip <> b.Zip
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE (a.ZipCode IS NOT NULL AND b.ZipCode IS NOT NULL AND a.ZipCode = b.ZipCode) 
OR (a.ZipCode IS NULL OR b.ZipCode IS NULL) AND a.City = b.City
```

Let's break it down:

```
 (a.ZipCode IS NOT NULL AND b.ZipCode IS NOT NULL AND a.ZipCode = b.ZipCode)
```

First, we need to make sure that neither zipcode is NULL (unknown)
If we have 2 zipcodes, we can compare them, if not, we want to compare cities:

```
OR (a.ZipCode IS NULL OR b.ZipCode IS NULL) AND a.City = b.City
```

Here we make sure that at least one of the zipcodes is NULL (unknown) otherwise we would prefer to compare zipcodes. Then we compare Cities.

You could skip the NULL check in the second part and simplify the where clause to:

```
WHERE (a.ZipCode IS NOT NULL AND b.ZipCode IS NOT NULL AND a.ZipCode = b.ZipCode) 
OR a.City = b.City
```

But in that case, it will not prioritize matching the ZipCode over the City, for example: If we have a city with ZipCode: 1000 and Name: Test, and another city with ZipCode: 2000, Name: Test.. it will now consider them to be a match.

When using an (INNER) JOIN, there is no difference wheter you specifiy the conditions in the JOIN or the WHERE clause, so these:

```
SELECT ... FROM a JOIN b ON a.id=b.a_id

SELECT ... FROM a, b WHERE a.id=b.a_id
```

Will produce the same result.